# layer is a part of cycle in its layer tree iOS 9 Swift 2

Tags: calayer, swift2, ios9

When I load my view controller I'm getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'layer <CALayer: 0x7fda42c66e30> is a part of cycle in its layer tree'
```

I don't know why. I think I might've added a third party framework that messed with layers, but I removed it in my troubleshooting. Any insights would be great.

## EDIT

It happens during `viewDidLoad` of my `tableViewcontroller`. I have a tableView on my second vc. I've narrowed it down to it crashing on setting the `heightForRowAtIndexPath` on the 4th custom cell. The cell is on a static `tableView`................. :/ Getting closer!

Here's my `heightForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    
    print("idx = \(indexPath.row)")
    
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath: indexPath)
}
```

Pretty generic. Any thoughts on where else this might be caused?

Comment: Can you show related codes?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I had the same error too and found this [fix](http://blog.benjamin-encz.de/ios-9-detects-cycles-in-layout-trees/)

It mentions to remove the accessoryView Outlet which you will see on the TableView.

To do this:

1. Click on the Table View
2. Go to the "Connections Inspector", it's the right window, the very last icon (looks like a circle with an arrow right)
3. Look for the accessoryView and disconnect the outlet

In the screenshot below, see the outlet you are to disconnect:

[image]

Comment: This is exactly what was causing my issue. I got it resolved. Thanks

Answer (score 58):

This might help someone still in trouble with this,
For me the issue was this

```
layer.addSublayer(layer)
```

Adding a layer to itself ‍♂️ . After this mistake I am planning to kill myself :(.

Comment: Hahah did the same thing!

Comment: Haha, I think there is a queue of people that have done this! lol

Comment: Same thing here, your comment saved my life :)

Comment: Ugh, I need to stop naming my test views `view` or remember to use `self.view` lol

Comment: Funny your nickname is `infiniteLoop` ) Thanks.

Comment: The same here! T_T

Comment: I did it because I have named my custom layer as 'lay' for testing and will never do it again, dang autocomplete haha.

Comment: Note to self: don't use `layer` as a variable name when creating new layers.

Answer (score 31):

check if you add self.view in self.view, exemple:

```
self.view.addSubview(view)
```

or

```
contentView.addSubview(self.view)
```

Comment: Thanks for saving me a ton a grief :thumbs_up:

Comment: Good answer, but it doesn't tell you what to do instead. In the above case you probably mean to be adding a view other than the self.view as your subview. May be obvious to more experienced ios devs, but this clarification would have helped me aha

Comment: This was my issue too

Answer (score 6):

One of my friend was facing the same issue. The root cause was lying in the viewForHeaderInSection delegate of UITableview.

He was adding a label in main view of the controller in this delegate. He was supposed to create a UIView and return it in this delegate but unfortunately
he was returning self.view there. So removing this code fixed the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to fix it but not in the way that I'd hoped. I ended up scratching the tableViewCell that was causing the issue and rebuilding all the layout constraints from scratch. Not ideal, but it worked. I hope someone can come along in the future and explain why this error happened! Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I solved one crash of this kind by removing the outlet to `File' s owner` in some of `xib` UI files. I answer here in case someone encounters a similar thing.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue too, and found out I accidentally created an outlet from the TableViewCell backgroundView to the TableView's view - DOH!

Answer (score 0):

**Also, when saving view as a variable inside UIViewController don't give it the name "view" cause "view" is saved to the UIViewController's View**

Answer (score 0):

For me the problem was
I created a cell created its class and made some `IBOutlet` after some time I realised that my project already have class for this cell. So, I deleted my class and assigned existing class to my cell but the forgot to break IBOutlet of the old class
So, solution is:
just go to `Connection Inspector` and remove all broken `IBOutlet`

[image: Please have a look of the pic]