# Crash on reload tableView from layer

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uirefreshcontrol

I have an UIViewController embed in one NavigationController who contain a TableViewController,

Sometime when I reload, only when I do big Swipe Up-Down I got this error

> 2017-05-04 15:40:40.333630+0200 NameOfMyApp[448:48840] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'CALayerInvalid', reason: 'layer  is a part of cycle in its layer tree'

Of course I search before the question, the answer I found was deprecated or not working, For exemple a lot of people answered by remove the outlet **accessoryView** from the TableView, here my connexion inspector [image]

I don't see no where this outlet

Edit:

In my UITableViewCell, I still don't have any accessoryView link
[image]

Edit2:

```
let refreshTableView: UIRefreshControl = UIRefreshControl()

override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        refreshTableView.addTarget(self, action: #selector(MainViewController.refreshMyTableView), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged) // Function who call the back, and after reload my tableview with self.tableView.reloadData()
        if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
            self.tableView.refreshControl = refreshTableView
        } else {
            tableView.addSubview(refreshTableView)
        }
```

Comment: what is the point of reloading the tabel-view's content form the _view-layer_ when it is a kinda MVC-fact that reloading is supposed to be triggered from the _controller-layer_ only?

Comment: @Basr Filali TableViewController is itself a controller why embded in UIController? and you do not require to confirm data source and delegate if using TableViewController.

Comment: @Tushar Sharma Because for that view I can't use a TableViewController, I need to use anUIViewController

Comment: @Holex, I don't understand your question, I reload, my tableView, for ask new data, from my backend

Comment: @BadrFilali Why not table views?

Comment: @BadrFilali, I don't understand why is that happening on the _view-layer_? so I don't understand what is not actually crystal-clear in my question...

Comment: @TusharSharma I will need at one moment some other information on the page, I don't want tableView in all the page

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32741827/1638273

Comment: @SeanLintern88 I see this thread no one of this answer work for me

Comment: Please show code.

Comment: @shallowThought I have only few line for that, I edit my question

Answer (score 1):

The `accessoryView` is part of the `UITableViewCell`, you are looking at UITableView outlets. You would need to select the `UITableViewCell` and check if you have something hooked to your `accessoryView` Outlet

Comment: I just look, on my UITableViewCell and I have nothing I just edit my question